# How can I add padding to fields in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, padding

I am using Django Admin to access to data of some projects. To be able to have a proper view I have some class:

```
class Whatever(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    view = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
```

To which I added the `__str__` method with a specific formatting that contains the [`{:X}` padding](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) to set X characters to a field:

```
    def __str__(self):
        username = self.user.username if self.user else ""
        return "{:25} - {:30} - {:32}".format(self.user., self.view, self.date)
```

However, in the Django admin, all the padding is ignored, so all I got is a set of lines on the format:

```
bla - my_view - 2019-05-14 17:18:57.792216+00:00
another_user - another_view - 2019-05-14 16:05:27.644441+00:00
```

Without any padding, while I would like something like:

```
bla            - my_view        - 2019-05-14 17:18:57.792216+00:00
another_user   - another_view   - 2019-05-14 16:05:27.644441+00:00
```

In normal Python, if I do:

```
class M(object): 

     def __init__(self): 
         self.a = "hola"
         self.b = "adeu"

     def __str__(self): 
         return "{:25} - {:30}.".format(self.a, self.b)
```

It works well:

```
>>> print(m)                                                                            
hola                      - adeu                          .
```

I'm in Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django admin doesn't modify your model string representation. Spaces cutoff happens when your browser render text. So in order to force non-breakable spaces, you can do this:

```py
def __str__(self):
    nonBreakSpace = u'\xa0'
    username = self.user.username if self.user else ""
    return "{} - {} - {}".format(str(self.user).ljust(25, nonBreakSpace),
                                 self.view.ljust(30, nonBreakSpace),
                                 str(self.date).ljust(32, nonBreakSpace)
                                 )
```

Comment: I checked the HTML code of the rendered text and there are no multiple spaces in there, so it must be lost somewhere in between. In any case, thanks for the trick, it is a nice one!!